# How to access version numbers directly from within a tex file?

Tags: xetex, tex-core

Is it possible (i.e. is there any command) to access the version numbers of LaTeX/XeTeX directly from within a tex file?

So far I am simply using a small script that does `latex --version` or `xetex --version`, takes just the first line of the output and inserts `\newcommand{\LaTeXVersion}{...}` or `\newcommand{\XeTeXVersion}{...}` at a given position in the tex file.

Comment: Which version do you want? That's the engine banner plus other 'stuff'.

Comment: Something like `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`. I just need the numbers for future reference to know what version I used to make the document.

Comment: Will it be sufficient to know just the engine number and not the versions of the used packages (can be updated independently I think). It still gives a hint though.

Comment: Yep, I guess this would be enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XeTeX supports the primitives `\XeTeXversion` and `\XeTeXrevision` to get the used version of XeTeX. XeTeX also implemnts the eTeX extensions, so the `\eTeXversion` and `\eTeXrevision` primitives are available too to get the eTeX version.

These are the middle parts of the version printed in the banner, for example if you have `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`, you can use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\the\eTeXversion\eTeXrevision-\the\XeTeXversion\XeTeXrevision
\end{document}
```

to get

```
2.6-0.99992
```

This should be enough to identify the engine. The `3.14159265` only says which TeX version your XeTeX is based on.

You also ask for the "LaTeX" version. The version of the LaTeX format is available as `\fmtversion`, but this is not what is shown when you call `latex --version`, because this command shows the version of the TeX engine used by `latex`, normally `pdfTeX`.
If you document uses pdfLaTeX and you want to get the version, you can use primitives similar to the XeTeX ones:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\the\eTeXversion\eTeXrevision-\the\pdftexversion.\pdftexrevision
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
2.6-140.19
```

But pdfTeX also allows you to access the full banner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pdftexbanner
\end{document}
```

On my system for example this gives

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) kpathsea version 6.3.0
```